# how to get ionic2 code from my own server and make it run on time?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Because of some reasons,I need to generate ionic2 code in my server, which written by java language.

In my java programming, I return a JSON object and this JSON object contains ionic2 code, for example:

```html
{"message":'"<ion-list><ion-item><input type='text' value='' placeholder='customerName'></ion-item></ion-list>"'}
```

And then, in my ionic2 project, I attempt to include these ionic2 code to my local ionic2 template.below is my code:

```js
private addComponent(template: string, selector: string) {
    @Component({ template: template, selector: selector })
    class TemplateComponent { }

    @NgModule({ declarations: [TemplateComponent] })
    class TemplateModule { }

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) => 
      comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    const component = this.placeholder.createComponent(factory);
  }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let data = { "UserId": "test11", "UserPwd": "000000", "uuid": "testuuid4ionic2" }
    this.dataService.queryData("logon", data)
      .subscribe(
      ResponseData => {
        console.log(ResponseData);
        console.log(typeof (ResponseData.message));
        this.addComponent(ResponseData.message, 'page-about-dynamic');},
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.addComponent(JSON.stringify(error), 'page-abount-dynamic');
      },
      () => {
        console.log("complete!");
      });

  }
```

And then, when i run my ionic2 project,I got flowing error message:

```
'ion-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-item' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

So I'm here to ask you professional guys, is there some way to acquire original ionic2 code from http server, and then make it run directly?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: i've never used ionic but the error message said enough...you need to import ionic module for angular 2 into your application. Something like `import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';` and   `imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(yourMainAppComponent)
  ]` probably in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: if you mean server side rendering.. there are discussions [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/support-for-angular-universal/49103).But dot think it works

Comment: @suraj yeah,I mean server side rendering.

Comment: as per the forum discussion it is not implemented yet..